# Can not connect Ubuntu Server ssh from outside

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, connection

We have ubuntu server installed on our desktop machine. It is connected modem with ethernet port. We can access it with ssh via inside of our network. But can not from outside.

Here is what we've done so far:

- We have static ip
- Dmz
  [dmz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJfNo.png)
- Our ubuntu server machine always picks `192.168.1.200` as stated in image
  [lan devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUoxM.png)
- We have port forwarding as stated in image
  [port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JQ1y.png)

when I run `ssh maviarge@213.XXXXXXX` from our LAN which holds ubuntu server machine

```
maviarge@213.XXXXXXX's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-104-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Thu 10 Mar 2022 08:45:36 AM UTC

  System load:  0.07               Processes:                166
  Usage of /:   2.0% of 438.13GB   Users logged in:          1
  Memory usage: 2%                 IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IPv4 address for enp3s0:  192.168.1.200
  Temperature:  50.0 C

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

But when I run `ssh -v maviarge@213.XXXXXXX` from outside of our wifi.

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\MaviArge/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 213.XXXXXXX [213.XXXXXXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 213.XXXXXXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 213.XXXXXXX port 22: Connection timed out
```

When I run `ping 213.XXXXXXX`  from outside

```
Pinging 213.XXXXXXX with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=67ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=46
Reply from 213.XXXXXXX: bytes=32 time=124ms TTL=46

Ping statistics for 213.XXXXXXX:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 67ms, Maximum = 124ms, Average = 98ms
```

Saw this command on internet `sudo lsof -i:22` and the output:

```
sudo lsof -i:22
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    3290     root    4u  IPv4  38814      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:58124 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3375 maviarge    4u  IPv4  38814      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:58124 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    4057     root    3u  IPv4  71589      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    4057     root    4u  IPv6  71591      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    5662     root    4u  IPv4  74261      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:60472 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    5746 maviarge    4u  IPv4  74261      0t0  TCP maviarge:ssh->host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net:60472 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Also nmap scan:

```
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-03-10 05:17 EST
Nmap scan report for host-213.XXXXXXX.reverse.superonline.net (213.XXXXXXX)
Host is up (0.14s latency).
Not shown: 96 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   filtered ssh
25/tcp   filtered smtp
5060/tcp filtered sip
5432/tcp open     postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.08 seconds
```

`sudo ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see here two possible issues:

- Firewall on your router : while you are redirecting the port 22 into NAT of your gateway, a timeout indicate no IP packet back from our router. You might check if you don't need to open port 22 on TCP into the Firewall configuration as well.
- (probably not this issue anymore since you edited the page) Routeback issue : some router forbids the possibility to have traffic incoming and outgoing from the same interface. It means you may not able to join port 22 using public IP from the same network than you server. You can check if this is a routeback issue by trying to connect on your server from another ISP (e.g from your house).

Comment: There is also a possibility that your ISP is blocking incoming connections to ssh port. Some ISPs do not allow that.